# Question about deploying a Shopify app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, shopify, shopify-app

I have question about Shopify app development and the deployment process.

I've used the getting started guide [here](https://shopify.dev/apps/getting-started/create), and I have an app that works fine when I use `npm run dev` and view the app in the store admin.

However, of course, once I stop the server from running, the app is no longer accessible.

I believe I need to deploy the app to Heroku (or something similar) in order to have it work in a non-development environment.

It doesn't seem like there is much guidance online from Shopify about the best way to go about this.

Does anyone know what steps I need to take in order to deploy my app to Heroku, so that I can use the app in by test store on another device?

It seems like every guide online stops JUST BEFORE explaining this process and I can't figure out why! I have tried everything online but nothing has worked:

- Adding the code to Github and connecting it to Heroku
- Using Docker

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have zero obligations to use Heroku. If you have an IP address dedicated to your house, you could host the App using your house. If you co-locate your own server at an Internet business, and they give you IP addresses you can use that. If you wanted to use Amazon directly, you could use EC2. If you wanted to use Linode, or Azure, or any other cloud service, feel free! It is up to you!

Using Heroku (built on AWS) is traditional only in the sense that it is the original **easy peasy hosting in the cloud** service. Play with Heroku by reading Heroku-specific documentation or hosting information. This has nothing to do with Shopify. Shopify only mentions Heroku because traditionally, developers used it. No other reason.

If you want to learn how to use Heroku, 100% there are blog posts within easy reach for you to study and learn from.